# Free Shipping with the Australia Post Shipping Extension

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

I'm using Expresso Store with the "Australia Post Shipping" extension.

Currently I'm attempting to order a single item with "Free Shipping" set, but it seems the Australia post extension is applying a shipping cost of $9.95 to the order.

I was wondering if the calculator ignores "Free shipping" items when calculating a shipping total, or if I'm doing something wrong?

If the extension ignores the "Free shipping" attribute, is it possible to check if the order consists of free shipping items, and render a different set of {shipping_options} in the checkout tag?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, and we have a fix for it coming out very soon.

In the meantime, if you would like to test the update please email support@exp-resso.com and we will get you a copy.

UPDATE: This has been fixed in version 1.0.2 of the Australia Post extension.

https://exp-resso.com/docs/shipping_aus_post.html